# 1988 F150 INLINE SIX no dash or interior lights,brake and tail lights are now inop

Tags: electrical, ford, f-150

no dash or interior lights,brake and tail lights are now inop ,FUSE KEEPS BLOWING

Comment: Welcome to the site. What exactly are you asking? What have you done to diagnose the issue?

Comment: There is a short somewhere. You'll have to trace. Did you swap any tungsten bulbs with LED? Even a lose terminal contact can cause a short at times.

Answer (score 2):

Fuses blow to protect the circuit, so you need to find the short-circuit.

Several ways to proceed : remove All the bulbs from one circuit, test and then if the fuse is still blowing do the same for another circuit.

Or, you could disconnect each circuit, but that may not be easy.

The point is you have to be methodical / logical and test each bulb and also each wire / cable.

Had a case once where the interior fuse blew each time the customer used the car... Long story, but we solved it when we had the customer sit in the seat - a broken spring came down and pierced the wire creating the short. Only difficult because we had sat in the seat but it did not happen for us - he weighed about 230lbs!

Comment: what is your opinion on LED resistors.

Comment: Why? Does not appear to be part of the OP's question.

Comment: In hvac, its not allowing LED bulbs. Only factory bulbs light up. LED run on 5v, factory tungsten on 14v.

Comment: A single LED needs about 1.5v, most are used in series so a 5 or 12v supply is appropriate. Why "factory tungsten" after market tungsten bulbs work fine...

Comment: I have the habit of changing every bulb to LED. But our oldest JDM import's hvac did not like the idea. I ordered a new set, each bulb from Honda costs 13.99 plus taxes. It comes with it's own socket plug. But I got a box full of 100 LED bulbs of 2mm and 5mm at 10 bucks.

Comment: Thank you. I feel stupid. You just gave me an idea. I'll connect multiple bulbs in sync.

Comment: Solar, its a failure. The tungsten bulbs all 8, work. But the LEDs in series did not illuminate.

Comment: You did make sure to identify the positive and negative terminals on each led?

Comment: Indeed. But the holder in a HVAC unit, cannot hold so many bulbs.

Answer (score 1):

check the turn signal switch behind steering wheel....mine was doing same thing. steering wheel would rub the wires and create the short